# Icinga 2: variable in display_name?

Tags: icinga, icinga2

Is it possible to pass a variable to `display_name` in Icinga2 configuration, e.g. for a service:

```
apply Service for (disk_name => config in host.vars.disks) to Host {
  import "generic-service"
  vars = vars + config
  display_name = "disk" //TODO: pass hdd name?
  check_command = "disk"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

```
apply Service for (disk_name => config in host.vars.disks) to Host {
  import "generic-service"
  vars = vars + config
  display_name = disk_name
  check_command = "disk"
}
```

Comment: Right, that was easy! Looks like concatenation is also possible `display_name = "disk " + disk_name`

Comment: Yes that is true